# bash function - variable value ignored

Tags: bash, function, variables

I am creating a kind-of alias for fast base64 encoding of strings. For it I have created following function and added it to my .bash_profile file:

```
# My functions
function b64() {
    perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("$1");'
}
```

The problem is that it encodes the string "$1" itself without processing actual value that I am "giving" to it in request:

```
$ b64 "test_value"
JDE=

$ echo -n "JDE=" | base64 -d
$1
```

I have tried using '$1' and "$1", without any quotes, but the problem persists still and it keeps encoding $1 as string and not a value.

Could you please check what am I missing here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong kind of quotes.  You can debug this more easily if you use `echo` to show what you're executing:

```
$ b64() { echo 'print encode_base64("$1");'; }
$ b64 foo
print encode_base64("$1");
```

```
$ b64() { echo "print encode_base64('$1');"; }
$ b64 foo
print encode_base64('foo');
```

Other debugging techniques exist - for example `printf '%q\n'` or `set -x`.

---

With this knowledge, you can write your `b64` as

```
b64() { perl -MMIME::Base64 -e "print encode_base64('$1');"; }
```

This gives me the expected result:

```
$ b64 foo
Zm9v
$ base64 -d <<<Zm9v
foo
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it did the trick. Will note these debugging tips.

Comment: Be aware that this is not robust programming: it will fail if the string contains single quotes (and, more dangerously, it is subject to arbitrary code execution).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the obvious quoting problem that prevents the expansion of `$1`, you shouldn't inject data like so in your program: you should treat data as data!

Now, I'm no Perl expert, but the following should be more robust:

```
b64() {
    perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64($ARGV[0]);' -- "$1"
}
```

Comment: That's much better than my quick fix, and deserves to become the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the fact that single quotes inhibit expansion.

```
perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("'"$1"'");'
```

Comment: I have tried applying these changes. After running new ~/.bash_profile it still parses "$1" itself unfortunately:
$ . ~/.bash_profile
All changes were successfully applied
$ b64 "test_val"
JDE=

Comment: What does your code look like now?

Comment: Like this:
function b64() {
    perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("'"$1"'");'
}

Comment: And are you sure this is the function your shell is picking up?

Comment: @TobySpeight: It does actually look like mine; I had to copy-and-paste it since no formatting was applied, but it does match.

Comment: There are no other functions under this profile actually, and there was no "b64" executable before I have added it. "b64" is listed when I try TABing available commands:
'$ b
b64
bonobo-activation-run-query 
base64'
..and so on.
I thought that it isn't added properly, but everything seems to show that it's done and resolved properly, excluding the problem with variable.

Comment: And `set` shows the updated function?

Comment: Just checked it, yes set shows same code as under .bash_profile file:
b64 ()
{
    perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("'"$1"'");'
}
Sorry for not formatting, still trying to figure it out in comments.

Comment: Be aware that this is not robust programming: it will fail if the string contains double quotes (and, more dangerously, it is subject to arbitrary code execution).